# React-Router-Dom `Link` changes route, but no component loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working with a react app, and I have the router setup, the issue is I currently have three components available to the user via the Link component and this is how those are in the jsx.

```
<Fragment>
    <NavItem>
       <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem>
       <Link to="/regiser">Register</Link>
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem>
       <Link to="/reset">Recover Account</Link>
    </NavItem>
</Fragment>
```

and the routes are defined with BrowserRouter aliased to Router

```
<Fragment>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
    <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
    <Route exact path='/reset' component={ResetUser} />
</Fragment>
```

The issue is this:

1. The user is presented with `Landing` component when at `/`
2. The user is presented with `Login` component when at `/login`
3. The user is presented with `ResetUser` component when at `/reset`
4. The user is not presented with a component at all when at `/register`

The `Register` component is defined like this:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

class Register extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello Register</div>
        );
    }
}
export default Register;
```

which is infuriating because it's really holding me up for testing authentication.......

Comment: It should be `<Link to="/register">`, not `<Link to="/regiser">.`

Comment: oh jeesh..... I need more eyes on this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the typo in regiser? it should be register!

Comment: A typo will always get you!